# About Conditional Probability, Circular Argument?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The following problem is about conditional probability.

We want to know the value $P(A \cap B)$ by the formula $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \times P(B|A)$.

The definition of $P(B | A)$ is $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$.

So, if I want to know $P(B | A)$, I have to know the value $P(A \cap B)$ previously.

I think this is a circular argment.

What should I do?

> Example: Drawing $2$ Kings from a Deck
>
> Event $A$ is drawing a King first, and Event $B$ is drawing a King second.
>
> $P(A) = \frac{4}{52}$
>
> $P(B|A) = \frac{3}{51}$
>
> And so:
>
> $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \times P(B|A) = (4/52)\times(3/51) = 12/2652 = 1/221$

Comment: $P(B\mid A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$ is definition.  $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B\mid A)$ is a result and is not itself a definition.  As such, the definitions are not in fact circular.  The definition for $P(A\cap B)$ is the same as the usual definition for probability for any other event, noting that $A\cap B$ is itself an event (*albeit one that is expressed with more than just one symbol*).

Comment: That being said, once you are comfortable with the concept of conditional probability and are able to quickly identify values, using the result above you can have an easier time calculating the probability of the intersection of two events like in your example.  If you want to avoid that, you certainly can.  E.g. for your example you could have used the sample space of all ways in which you draw two cards in sequence without replacement, the sample space being of size $52\cdot 51$, and noting there are $4\cdot 3$ elements in the sample space corresponding to both cards being kings.

Comment: @JMoravitz: That looks like an answer to me :-)