# The multiplication law in probability is the easiest proposition to prove in the world. Why useful?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I think the multiplication law in probability is the easiest proposition to prove in the world.

Why is the multiplication law useful?

> Multiplication Law:
> Let $A$ and $B$ be events and assumu $P(B)\ne 0$. Then $$P(A\cap B) = P(A|B) P(B).$$

> My proof of this proposition is here:
> By definion, $P(A|B) := \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$, so $P(A|B) P(B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} P(B) = P(A\cap B)$.
> Q.E.D.

I think this proposition is too easy to be useful.
Why is the multiplication law useful?

By the way, I asked a similar question before, but I was not able to understand the answer. ([About Conditional Probability, Circular Argument?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2879032/384082))

Comment: What makes you think easy things cannot be useful? The existence of prime numbers is fairly easy as well, but undoubtedly useful. Both prime number decomposition and multiplication law allow you to reduce a calculation to the calculation of two or more (hopefully easier to understand) things

Comment: Another example of something incredibly easy that is used all the time:  $-x=x$ implies $x=0$ in any field not of characteristic 2.  Trivial to prove but used countless times

Comment: I learnt $$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$ as Bayes' theorem and not the definition of $P(A|B)$. Of course "theorem" is somewhat exaggerating here. We started with $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B|A)=P(B)\cdot P(A|B)$ from which Bayes' theorem follows immediately.

Comment: Solving a linear equation system with two variables is also very easy. Would you consider this to be not useful as well ? Weird philosophy that something must be complicated to be useful.

Comment: As a rule, simpler and easier results are more useful than difficult ones. The fact that, say, the product of two positive numbers is positive, must be a million times as useful as Fermat's last theorem or the four color theorem.